# MFC how to know a resizing of view is finished

Tags: mfc

I am wondering how to catch the fact that a view (CView in a CMDIChildWnd frame) has been resized, and that the user just released the left mouse button.
None of OnSize, OnSizing and OnLButtonUp work.
I have tried the solution in http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=59476 and it doesn't work.
I am working on VC2010 with W7.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WM_NCLBUTTONUP. I don't know if a view can be resized other than by the mouse, but if it can you probably also want to respond to WM_EXITSIZEMOVE as in the link you gave.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I added also the management of SIZE_MAXIMIZED / SIZE_MINIMIZED in the OnSize function and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to do this. I used a combination of OnSysMessage to capture the SC_SIZE and SC_MOVE event and WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE and WM_EXITSIZEMOVE within the CMDIChildWnd derived class.  Within the OnSysMessage handler I set a public variable for IsSizing. I can then check the variable within the OnEnterSizeMove function and act accordingly. Within the OnExitSizeMove function, it resets the variable to FALSE.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildFrame, CMDIChildWnd)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CChildFrame)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE, OnEnterSizeMove)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, OnExitSizeMove)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And for the handlers:

```
void CChildFrame::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch(nID&0xfff0)
    {
    case SC_SIZE:
        m_bIsSizing = TRUE;
        break;
    case SC_MOVE:
        m_bIsSizing = FALSE;
        break;
    }
    
    CMDIChildWnd::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
}
LRESULT CChildFrame::OnEnterSizeMove(UINT wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(m_bIsSizing)
    {
        TRACE("CChildFrame::OnEnterSizeMove\n");
    }
    return 0; //don't flag we processed the message
}
LRESULT CChildFrame::OnExitSizeMove(UINT wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if(m_bIsSizing)
    {
        TRACE("CChildFrame::OnExitSizeMove\n");
        m_bIsSizing = FALSE; // set to false before calling OnSizing
        CRect dlgRect;
        pView->GetClientRect(dlgRect);
        pView->InvalidateRect(NULL, FALSE);
        pView->SendMessage(WM_SIZE, WPARAM(SIZE_RESTORED), MAKELONG(dlgRect.Width(), dlgRect.Height()));
    }
    return 0; //don't flag we processed the message
}
```

Then within your View code, you can check if the Frame is sizing within your OnSize handler.

```
void CMyView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CChildFrame* pFrame=(CChildFrame*)GetParentFrame();
    if(!pFrame->m_bIsSizing) {
        CWaitCursor cur;
        //DO UPDATE CODE
    }
}
```